# Cassandra Unknown command bootstrap

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am new to cassandra but it seems the `nodetool bootstrap` command is not working.

```
huangg@cassandra-mpsre01-sjc1:~$ nodetool help bootstrap
Unknown command bootstrap
huangg@cassandra-mpsre01-sjc1:~$ nodetool bootstrap resume
nodetool: Found unexpected parameters: [bootstrap, resume]
See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help <command>'.
huangg@cassandra-mpsre01-sjc1:~$ nodetool help |grep bootstrap
    rebuild                      Rebuild data by streaming from other nodes (similarly to bootstrap)
```

Is it a version issue?

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.9 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

I want to use it because I want to resume a node after I decommission it. Right now, after I decommission a node, I have to stop cassandra service and then restart the cassandra service. I guess bootstrap can be used after the decommission command, to commission the node.

nodetool join is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things here 
1. First the commands which you specified don't seem correct. 
For Bootstrap you can probably use the following link and see the correct syntax.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/tools/toolsBootstrap.html

2. Now after the node is decommissioned, you would want to rebuild it from another node and then work with it as the other nodes are working.
   For that you can use nodetool rebuild. 
   https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRebuild.html

Both are similar commands, but you can see which suits your scenario best and use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`nodetool bootstrap` doesn't exist in c* 2.1.9. `nodetool rebuild` is the closest command

> $ nodetool help rebuild NAME
>
> ```
>     nodetool rebuild - Rebuild data by streaming from other nodes (similarly
>     to bootstrap)
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>           nodetool [(-h  | --host )] [(-p  | --port )]
>                   [(-pw  | --password )]
>                   [(-pwf  | --password-file )]
>                   [(-u  | --username )] rebuild [--]
>
> OPTIONS
>           -h , --host 
>               Node hostname or ip address
>
> ```
>     -p <port>, --port <port>
>         Remote jmx agent port number
>
>     -pw <password>, --password <password>
>         Remote jmx agent password
>
>     -pwf <passwordFilePath>, --password-file <passwordFilePath>
>         Path to the JMX password file
>
>     -u <username>, --username <username>
>         Remote jmx agent username
>
>     --
>         This option can be used to separate command-line options from the
>         list of argument, (useful when arguments might be mistaken for
>         command-line options
>
>     <src-dc-name>
>         Name of DC from which to select sources for streaming. By default,
>         pick any DC
> ```